# Scraping Infinite scroll page

Tags: python, python-3.x, ajax, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to **scrape** a infinite scroll ajax request page but not able to go the next page and get the yield items. I'm able to get the response.txt. I tried debbuging but not able get any solution. Can anyone help me in out in this.

```
import scrapy
 
class InfiniteScrollingSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'wegotthiscovered_review'
    scrolling_url = 'https://wegotthiscovered.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php'
 
    def start_requests(self):
        yield scrapy.FormRequest(
            self.scrolling_url,
            formdata={
                'action': "face3_infinite_scroll",
                'page': '1',
                'attrs': "{\"id\":\"1\",\"order\":\"\",\"orderby\":\"\",\"catnames\":\"movies+reviews\",\"postnotin\":\"905069,904520,904521,903475,901576,900303,893944,895136,891795,886876,884402,881283\",\"timestampbefore\":1591800990}"
            },
            callback=self.parse_page,
            meta={'page': 1},
        )
 
    def parse_page(self, response):
        next_page = response.meta.get('page') + 1
        print('next_page:', next_page)
        print(response.text)
 
        json_data = json.loads(response.text)
        print(json_data.keys())        
        print('success:', json_data.get('success'))        
        print('data:', json_data.get('data'))        
       
        if not json_data.get('success') or not json_data.get('data') or not json_data['data'].get('content'):
            return
       
        articles = scrapy.Selector(text=json_data['data']['content']).css('article')
        for article in articles:
            yield {
                'page_title': article.css('h4 ::text').extract_first().strip(),
                'review_link': article.css('h4 ::attr(href)').extract_first().strip(),
            }
        print('next page >>>')
        yield scrapy.FormRequest(
            self.scrolling_url,
            formdata={
                'action': "face3_infinite_scroll",
                'page': str(next_page),
                "query_args":"{\"archive_type\":\"masonry\",\"show_first\":false,\"columns\":2,\"meta_cat\":false,\"meta\":true,\"summary\":true,\"standard_summary\":\"excerpt\",\"more_button\":false,\"reduce_margin\":false,\"orientation\":\"landscape\",\"list_width\":\"6\",\"widgets\":false,\"widgets_sidebar\":\"sidebar-archive\",\"widgets_after\":3,\"widgets_repeat\":false,\"highlight\":\"featured\",\"pagination_type\":\"ajax\",\"infinite_load\":true}"

            },
            callback=self.parse_page,
            meta={'page': next_page},
        )
```

Comment: Bit confuseed. you said infinite scrolling, which I assume it's for a given page and so how do you expect it to go to the next page?

Comment: its a infinite scroll page you go to website and check. @AzyCrw4282